# Why won't spell check let me check just a selection in Word 2016?

Tags: microsoft-word, office365, spell-check

A recent update to Office 365 denied me the ability to spell-check just a selection of a document. I type many long documents and need to be able to just check the newest thing I typed. Please help.

Comment: I'm guessing you don't have spellcheck as you type enabled.

Comment: Please provide us with more specific information than "a recent update".

Answer (score 0):

You can just check portions of a word doc by selecting with your mouse then click Spellcheck or F7. Perhaps you mean the Word Online??